# Sending Left control key only

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to send the left control key only, not with any combination.
when I try to do so using the following code it only blocks my keyboards input
and doesn't really send it.

```
        INPUT input;
        WORD vkey = VK_LCONTROL;
        input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        input.ki.time = 0;
        input.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
        input.ki.wVk = vkey;
        input.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

        input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Comment: What specifically, are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to simulate input in a game, for instance? If so, which one. Otherwise, for which application do you wish to use this?

Comment: @enhzflep ya it's meant to be for a game (Conquer online) , the game basically needs you to hold ctrl to move in it , I can send keys to the game but I can't do it with the ctrl key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to simule a key with a **keybd_event**

```
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL,0x9d,0 , 0); //Press
//if u want u can use a sleep here to key hold
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL,0x9d,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0); //Release
```

You can see more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: it worked thanks :) I guess I should've added a delay for it to hold.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to put a delay, use **Sleep(_dwMilliseconds_)** Between the 2 keybd_event

Comment: keybd_event is deprecated, use SendInput

Comment: `keybd_event()` is just a wrapper for `SendInput()`, so do use `SendInput()` directly instead.